# How can I check/uncheck all CheckBoxes inside a GroupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with several GroupBoxes. Each GroupBox contains several CheckBoxes inside it. Each GroupBox also has (outside of it) two associated buttons that uncheck/check all CheckBoxes inside the linked GroupBox.

My plan was to use an enhanced for loop to iterate through all the CheckBoxes inside each GroupBox. However, GroupBoxes lack the required property to make the loop work (getEnumerator?).

Additionally, I need to make it so every time I check or uncheck a CheckBox manually, a TextBox gets update with the sum of the values stored on the tag property of the checked CheckBoxes.

I found some similar questions of people wanting to check/uncheck every CheckBox in the form. Here's the code adapted to my app.

```
private void CalculateComplementPrice()
{
    try
    {
        double total = 0;
        foreach (Control c in Controls) //I don't want to iterate through all the form
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;
                if(cb.Checked == true)
                {
                    total += Convert.ToDouble(cb.Tag);
                }
            }
        }
        tbComplementsPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error on the complement GroupBox", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to iterate through all the components of a GroupBox without having to iterate through all the form?

==Update==

I changed some of the code I found previously:

```
private void CalculateComplementPrice()
{
    double total = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.ToString().StartsWith("System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox"))
            {
                foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is CheckBox)
                    {
                        if (((CheckBox)c).Checked == true)
                        {
                            total += Convert.ToDouble(c.Tag);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    tbComplementPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", total);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error calculating the complement price", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Now it does what I want it to do, but I still have to iterate through all the components in order to find the CheckBoxes. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double total = 0;
try
{
    foreach (GroupBox ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()) //We get all of groupboxes that is in our form (We want the checkboxes which are only in a groupbox.Not all of the checkboxes in the form.)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox c in ctrl.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) //We get all of checkboxes which are in a groupbox.One by one.
        {
            if (c.Checked == true)
            {
                total += Convert.ToDouble(c.Tag);
            }
        }
    }
    tbComplementPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", total);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error calculating the complement price", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work

```
foreach(CheckBox c in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {
                c.Checked = true;
            }
```

Comment: Best answer. Just don't forget to import Linq:
`using System.Linq;`